# Mitm proxy using on Windows

Tags: proxy, mitmproxy

I have installed and run mitm proxy (on a Windows machine). Now I want to get the SSL key of the proxy. So anybody know where mitm proxy store this key?

Thanks in advance

Jelena

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can find the generated Mitm root certificate in the user profile after you have run mitmproxy for at least one time:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.mitmproxy
```

Alternatively you can simply browse to `http://mitm.it` using a web browser that is configured to use Mitmproxy. This web page is generated by your mitmproxy instance and allows to download the generated Mitm root CA certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://mitm.it and then from there try to download the certificate for your specific Operating System